# Change Owner of a script in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, autosys

I have a unix shell script file whose owner is "xyz" when run deletes some specific files.

I want to trigger this script to delete files in some other directory where the owner for the files to be deleted is different from the owner of the script. Is this possible? Is this possible to run this script as different user so that it can delete those new files?

EDIT : I use Autosys to periodically trigger this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **chmod** the files that need to be deleted first if you have sufficient rights. Afterwards your script, no matter what user it executes, will succeed.

Examples : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: yes, but will it be able to delete files owned by a different user?

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to delete them if you could chmod them?

Comment: user2133404 : yes you can

Comment: UpAndAdam : you could do the chmod with a different user using another autosys job.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use `sudo` for that:

```
sudo -u ANOTHER_USER /path/to/the/script.sh
```

However, your current account needs proper permissions to do so. You can configure those permissions using the file `/etc/sudoers`.

You'll find a ton of articles out there how to use `sudo`. This for example: [http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:*Ch09*:_Linux_Users_and_Sudo](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch09_%3a_Linux_Users_and_Sudo)

Comment: I dont have sudo permissions on this server. I use a autosys script which periodically triggers this script.

Comment: Then this is not possible. You are actually experiencing security restrictions.